# Error 1064 (42000) on create procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having this specific error when trying to create a stored procedure on MySQL database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS(TABLENAME VARCHAR(50)) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SolarTV' AND TABLE_NAME=TABLENAME; 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do here is temporarily change the delimiter while defining the procedure, then set it back to `;` after the procedure has been created. Otherwise it'll get confused when it sees the first `;` from within the procedure definition. Example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS(TABLENAME VARCHAR(50)) 
BEGIN 
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SolarTV' AND TABLE_NAME=TABLENAME; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: OK what is the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: Sounds like you're just invoking it incorrectly... Maybe try this: `CALL SolarTV.GET_COLUMNS('TABASSINANTES');` -- and if you're still having problems, try running this query to see under which database(s) the procedure has been stored: `SELECT db, name, type FROM mysql.proc WHERE name LIKE 'GET\_COLUMNS';`